# Changes in MySQL lost after restoring backup

Tags: mysql, virtual-machine, backup

We have OpenSuse Linux with MySQL+APache+PHP web application in Hyper V virtual machine.

We create backups each day.

After restoring backups we noticed that the changes in the MySQL database are not saved. Please advise.

Comment: How you run restore operation?

Comment: Yes, of course. After restore we noticed that the changes in mysql are not saved.

Comment: What changes are not saved, or do you mean restored?

Comment: Are you sure that the backup is backing up ALL the tables?

Comment: **Basically there is nowhere near enough information in this question for anyone to do anything other than make guesses**

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I will try to be more specific. We imported mysql database in phpmyadmin two months ago and worked normally and all entered data were visible normally on line.  We restored backup created two days ago and we noticed that in all backups there are saved tables on of databse that we imported in phpmyadmin two months ago. All what was changed in teh last two months was not saved.

Comment: I see 3 things that could have gone wrong: 1. You didn't backup correctly. 2. Something broke the backup. 3. You didn't restore correctly. So you will have to elaborate a lot more and explain what you did to backup and how you restored it. Maybe you copied the whole vm or snapshot. Or you ran mysqldump and stored it on an external drive. Or an internal drive. Or you used a backup tool. Maybe one that cloned the harddrive. And to restore it, you copied the whole vm back. Or imported the (maybe too old) sql dump. Or mounted the clone and copied the data directory. Or did something else.

Comment: Please ask mor einformation that might be helpful to you.  Teh backup method is bare-metal and we expected that it will backup everything. But, it backed up everything except database.

Comment: Hello backup was not done using mysql backlup methods. It is done by using backup bare metal method in Hyper V on Windows server.  We restored whole virtual hard disk and changes in mysql were not saved. Is it possible that during backup database was in some temp folder and that after restore it does not read anything from /temp so the changes are not visible?

Comment: The bare metal recovery does not (necessarily) mean that you get a full backup. The backup itself might only contain e.g. the system partition. Or only the system partition got refreshed and the rest stayed in the state of the last full backup. Also it might be there but you might have choosen to only restore the system without data. So please check your backup settings and your backup content and your restore settings. You are still very very vague in describing what you did.